# additionaldata in HERE Maps Geocoding and Search API v7 Rest

Tags: here-api

It is possible to use somehow

`&additionaldata=IncludeMicroPointAddresses,true`

query parameter for geocode request in REST API v7

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html

or it`s possible only in  old (and actively not maintained) API ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to HERE Shruti Kuber from  HERE Maps Slack channel:

"This is a known issue and  the parameter is not yet supported in the new API. You can keep using the older one for now and we will publish when the new one has the capability"

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/release_notes/topics/known-issues.html